# Apache - Rewrite dynamic subdomains and URL parameters

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with rewrite condition and rule in Apache2.
I want to have dynamic subdomains and dynamic folders, which will rewrite to php script.
For example:

```
sub1.example.com/folder1  => do.php?a=sub1&b=folder1
sub2.example.com/folder2  => do.php?a=sub1&b=folder2
```

It will looks like every subdomain has own folders. But some subdomain (admin etc) will not be rewrited.

I know how to rewrite subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ do.php?a=%1 [L,P]
```

but I don't know, how to do dynamic folders in subdomains.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this example can help you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond &#37;{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?do\.php$
RewriteRule .? do.php?url=%1&path=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```