# Apache rewrite condition for subdomain and URL including numbers

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website and I want to 404 all incoming traffic from subdomain like `sub.example.de` but not `www.example.de` and not `example.de`

like this ([Apache - Rewrite dynamic subdomains and URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111014/apache-rewrite-dynamic-subdomains-and-url-parameters))

```
RewriteCond &#37;{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

However when the requested URI is like this `/go/12345`, I don't want he rule to apply no matter if there is a subdomain or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule with a negative pattern in`RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond &#37;{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^go/12345/?$ - [L,R=404,NC]
```